Would this type of window insulation be effective in cooling my room and keep heat out?
I have 2 sliding windows in my room, both windows have window type AC units either in front or next to the back-side of the AC units (I guess the radiator/hot side of the AC. Idk much about AC parts). My country has tropical weather so by this time it's very hot and according to our news, there is a chance that the heat index could reach up to 52°C (125.6°F).
So I thought of finding a way to block out heat from the windows and found this. I'll also be using cloth duct tape to seal the gaps from the sliding windows.
I'll also be installing rubber strips on the sides and top of my doorway as well as a leather and foam door gap filler under the door to further reduce the cool air produced by the AC from getting out.
Basically trying to make my room almost airtight and hopefully lessen electricity consumption and lessen the stress of my AC unit trying to cool the room.
Here's what the window insulation sheet look like: https://imgur.com/a/tJGpnaq

You could test it out very cheaply: cover the windows in aluminum foil. For extra insulation, leave a couple cm of air between the glass and the foil and seal the edges with tape.

No insulation will be effective in cooling your room.
